# Amount of Data Required for Significance Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I'm wondering how the following two approaches to determining the amount of data
required for ascertaining statistical significance are related.

Assume I know the ratio of the first and second moments of a data sample, and that
the population of sample means looks sufficiently Normal such that a $t$-test is
valid.

The first approach relates to backing out the amount of data required for a one
sample $t$-test to be significant at a given confidence level, when comparing
the sample mean to 0.

$$
P[t > \alpha] = P[\frac{\bar{x} - 0}{s/\sqrt{n}} > \alpha]
$$

Since this is a $t$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, we could solve
this by solving for $n$ and $\alpha$ iteratively, given some confidence level,

e.g. for a confidence level of 95% and a ratio $\bar{x}/s = 0.5$

```
> (alpha <- qt(0.95, 10))
[1] 1.812461
> (n <- (alpha/0.5)^2)
[1] 13.14006

> (alpha <- qt(0.95, n-1))
[1] 1.780576
> (n <- (alpha/0.5)^2)
[1] 12.6818

> (alpha <- qt(0.95, n-1))
[1] 1.786341
> (n <- (alpha/0.5)^2)
[1] 12.76406
```

Therefore in this case, to reject the null that the mean is 0 at the 95%
confidence level, we would need 13 observations.

The second approach, discussed [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/how-much-data-is-needed-to-validate-a-short-horizon-trading-strategy#1904), looks at the confidence interval
around the estimate.

$$
\Delta = (\bar{x} + SE\cdot\alpha) - (\bar{x} - SE\cdot\alpha)
   = 2\cdot SE \cdot \alpha = 2\cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt{x}} \cdot \alpha
$$

rearranging we have

$$
n = (\frac{s}{\Delta})^2(2 \cdot \alpha)^2
$$

---

I understand that the first approach is testing whether the sample mean differs
from 0, whereas the second approach pertains to a confidence interval around the
estimated mean, but I'm unclear how these are related. It seems like there is
some relation between these two approaches that I'm struggling to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is generally known as *power analysis*. Accordingly, it is a process for determining the sample size needed to detect significance for a hypothesized effect size, or vice versa.  You are correct, the two approaches you mention are related. The reference below spells some of this out. You'll see that effect side measures (e.g., Cohen's *d*) takes both mean differences and variability into account.

[power analysis](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html)